# How use Object while creating Generic class?

Tags: java, class, object, addition, calculator

I want to create a generic class of `Object`.

```
class Calculator<Object> {

         // addition function for addition of two numbers (Integer , Float)

    Object addition(Object first, Object second)
    {
        
        return  ;    //Should return as Object

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance...
(P.S. NOT going to use it in project......Asking just for my conceptual clarity)

Comment: Whilst it is legal to declare a type variable called `Object`, I would strongly discourage it.

Comment: You can’t. While you can add two integers or two floats, it makes no sense to add two objects, and you will not be able to write code that does. You may try `class Calculator<T extends Number>`, but even that will give you challenges. I can definitely write a number class hat will cause your code to break.

Comment: There is no good way to do what you're trying to do, and no good reason to do it anyway.

Comment: You can't just make up syntax and expect it to work magically.

Comment: Alas, Java generics are not designed to let you write something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define a generic class, better use a capital letter as the generic type name, for example

```
class Calculator<T> {
    T addition(T first, T second) {
        //how to add two generic objects?
    }
}
```

Maybe you don't want to add two arbitrary objects, but [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)s

```
class Calculator<T extends Number> {
    T addition(T first, T second) {
        return first + second; //does not compile!
    }
}
```

The sad news is that `Number` does not have an `add` method, and you can't just use the `+` operator. Maybe you can define an abstract class or interface

```
interface Calculator<T extends Number> {
    default T addition(@Nullable T first, @Nullable T second) {
        if (first == null || second == null) {
            return first == null ? second : first;
        }
        return nonNullAddition(first, second);
    }
    
    T nonNullAddition(@NotNull T first, @NotNull T second);
}
```

and implement for the cases you need

```
class IntCalculator implements Calculator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer nonNullAddition(@NotNull Integer first, @NotNull Integer second) {
        return first + second;
    }
}

class BigDecimalCalculator implements Calculator<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public BigDecimal nonNullAddition(@NotNull BigDecimal first, @NotNull BigDecimal second) {
        return first.add(second);
    }
}
```

Yet, this might be cumbersome. If you don't care about precision, you can cast (more properly it is a [widening conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) everything to `double`; if you care about precision you can use `BigDecimal`.

```
class Calculator {
    public double addition(double first, double second) {
        return first + second;
    }

    public BigDecimal addition(BigDecimal first, BigDecimal second) {
        return first.add(second);
    }
}
```

and use it in the following way:

```
double f = 1.0;
int i = 2;
Calculator calc = new Calculator();
double sum = calc.addition(f, i);
BigDecimal preciseSum = calc.addition(new BigDecimal(f), new BigDecimal(i));
```